# Jenkins Docker Pipeline Plugin - support of --email option in withDockerRegistry

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

Recently upgraded from Jenkins 1.x to 2.x and now I'm receiving errors during the pipeline

```
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u anonymous -p ******** https://registry:5000
Email: EOF
```

I'm using an old version of docker that still requres the email option when using docker login.  I was using version `1.12` of the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) and now I'm on the most recent `1.17`.  I can't find anything in the changelog that discusses the deprecation of this option nor does this appear to be an open source repository.

Just wondering if anyone can update me or if I'm going to be forced to upgrade my docker version?

Comment: Can you not specify what you need in the credentials id within Jenkins?

Comment: I can specify the docker username and password, but I don't think you can add an email to a credential, or pass in an option to withDockerRegistry to use an email.  My guess is that the plugin just attempts a docker login, and in older versions set some default email for you, but now it doesn't.  I can't look at the source code to confirm though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just updating my version of docker to `18.06.0-ce`  I did open an issue against the plugin, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52991.  But my guess is it's just going to get closed and is just going to be something no longer supported.

Comment: @IliaShakitko I updated my answer. I used the latest ce at that time , 18.06.0